# Verifying a Google ID Token in Django

Tags: python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, google-signin

I have a React Native Android app which uses Google Sign-In to get the users profile and email information and produces an ID token (using https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin). The sign in works and I am displaying the users name, email, photo etc on the app.

I am then trying to send the ID token to a Django + DRF backend so that it can be validated and a relevant user account created and/or logged in. I am following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Here is my code for the endpoint. For now I have just been copying the ID token produced by the app and sending it to the backend via Postman.

```
class GoogleView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        token = {'idToken': request.data.get('idToken')}
        print(token)

        try:
            idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), MY_APP_CLIENT_ID)
            print(idinfo)

            if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
                raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

            return Response(idinfo)
        except ValueError:
            # Invalid token
            content = {'message': 'Invalid token'}
            return Response(content)
```

When I send the POST request, the first print statement runs confirming that the token was received correctly. However the second print statement never runs and I always get the 'Invalid token' response. So, I believe verify_oauth2_token is failing somehow but it doesn't give me anymore information.

I have never used Google Sign In before so it's entirely possible I've missed something obvious. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, did you do any particular settings in Django? Hi, I got this to work in a regular python file but when I do the same thing in Django, I get an exception that says: <module 'google.oauth2.id_token' from '/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py'> could not be converted to bytes

What would be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this myself with the help of a friend. Just had to change the exception handling to display the relevant error and then pass token['id_token'] instead of the full token dict. New code:

```
class GoogleView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        token = {'id_token': request.data.get('id_token')}
        print(token)

        try:
            # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
            idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token['id_token'], requests.Request(), MY_APP_CLIENT_ID)
            print(idinfo)

            if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
                raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

            return Response(idinfo)
        except ValueError as err:
            # Invalid token
            print(err)
            content = {'message': 'Invalid token'}
            return Response(content)
```

Comment: How do you route to this http handler? (aka what are you doing in urls.py?)

Comment: Hi, sorry I just saw your question and this is probably too late to be helpful, however this is how I route to the view in urls.py: 

`urlpatterns = [
path('api/token/google/', views.GoogleView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair_google'),
]`

Comment: What are the packages you importing in your view.py file? I mean as for example `from rest_framework.views import APIView`? for above class view

Comment: Hi, I got this to work in a regular python file but when I do the same thing in Django, I get an exception that says: <module 'google.oauth2.id_token' from '/Users/femindharamshi/Documents/S22/WAD/TeamProject/s22_team_1/backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/oauth2/id_token.py'> could not be converted to bytes

What would be causing this issue?

Comment: I get the error: `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'` when calling `id_token.verify_oauth2_token`